# Domain objects encapsulation: static methods vs Service classes

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I've read in DDD book (Eric Evans) that procedures which require to be used in presentation should be moved to services classes. For instance BankAccountManagementService has ChangeBankAccount, GetByAccountId ... methods.

However I need to encapsulate setters of some properties to forbid assigning them from other business objects. As C# doesn't have friendly classes it is impossible to use this type of encapsulation in case of Services. But it is possible to do it using static methods of BankAccount business object.

(1) How do you solve this limitation in case of using Services for mentioned above reason?

Edit: additional question

(2) Why it is bad to use static method instead of services? I can place them in separate partial class file to not mix proc code with Entity code.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If properties of a domain object should not be set (immutable), then make them private (or protected).

The service method that is responsible for altering the private properties of a domain object would perform necessary validation and or permissions checks and create a new object via one of its constructors (including its id) with the properties it wants to change and save that object.

Another option would be to put a set method on your domain object which takes the new value, and some kind of permission object, or attribute the method to require certain privileges. That way you can constrain where the set is called from.

EDIT:
Making things static is an architectural black hole: 
You cant inherit from them or alter them in any way. 
It makes it impossible to use dependency injection.
Versioning is harder; once you have made then static and the are used, it is hard to reverse that decision.
Also, your static method may not use instance data today, but it may need to in the future.

When the methods are instance methods, you can make use of polymorphism and generics, creating a generic ServiceBase class and putting commonly used methods there.

Comment: Thanks for answer, however why to not use static methods instead of service without any problems?

Comment: Edited Answer to reflect static comment

Comment: @Danil: The example I was given was this. Imagine you have a BankService class. It has all the methods you need to manipulate bank accounts. What happens if you need different methods according to a country? The method names could be the same but their processes could be slightly different. This is where the idea of having different instances justifies itself. Having two or more instances allows you to swap Services around while keeping the same placeholder (usually an interface). Doing this with static only would be impractical. In fact, static methods should be limited to utilities classes.

Comment: agreed with James. +1 for the comment.